# Cannot find module 'lodash/isEmpty'

Tags: npm, lodash

Got an error after doing npm start

Error:- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72b80088aca1e939da5760bee6b39570

Things I did:-
1- I removed lodash folder from node_modules folder, then I cleared the cache using npm cache clear. After that I did npm install, as lodash was present in package.json. But I am getting the same error

2- Then used node version 8.0.0, got same error

3- I've used 'require' to import lodash/isEmpty. So, I don't there is any spelling mistake.

4- I've already checked the presence of isEmpty.js file inside lodash folder, under node_modules directory. And it's there.

Update:- I removed the node_module folder and then I removed the cache using npm cache clean. After that I did npm install. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please show your require statement.

Comment: I have use require statement in three .js files.

Comment: const isEmpty = require('lodash/isEmpty')

Comment: My package.json file :- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0fb972225b0707d45f32faeae2243ec

Comment: Generally, on stackoverflow its preferred you update the question with any additional code as needed - saves people from going into the gist and the gist potentially missing in the future

Comment: Your package.json doesn't contain webpack, but you are using it as part of your build runs... Can you update the answer with your webpack config as well

Comment: Hi Chris, actually, my friend wrote this code. So, I checked all the imports and found that his code imports one file from another folder which contains isEmpty fuction of lodash. So, I did npm install in that folder and now it's working.

Comment: Thank you for your time and support.